# mysterious running time for delayed job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I'm working with [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) on my Rails app. Here is my code:

```
run_at = 4.hours.from_now
# run_at is actually a calculation according to timezone and other stuff
MyModel.delay(run_at: run_at).create(some_params)
```

mysteriously, yesterday night, my job starts directly. This means 2 possible things :

1. `run_at` is basically `now` or in the past.
2. `DelayedJob` model did do the delay.

I've checked 3 times the calculation. `run_at` were not equal to `now` yesterday night.

This problem occurred 4 times yesterday around the same hour and half.
Actually it's 2 times 2 bad delayed tasks.

FYI : I didn't restart my server yesterday night.

Is it possible that `DelayedJob` squeezed my running hour?

**EDIT**
I've checked my data. I've stored the exact hour of the supposed starting job. it was in the past.. My mistake.

Comment: Did you check calculation result in actual production logs or just by looking in code? Servers may have different time zones set or obsolete tzdata

Comment: I checked it right now. I don't find any text about `DelayedJob` creation. But the data stored my database tell it has been delayed.. at the exact time (h:m:s) where the method is called. Is it possible to called `run_at` without seeing any `DelayedJob` database line created? Timezone is ok on my production server. I checked it.

Comment: Queries to db are logged at `:debug` log level, in production default is `:info`, so that is normal

Answer (score 2):

My bad, the task was supposed to run in the past (`run_at` < `now`). That's why it started immediately.